# invalid_request: The `redirect_uri` parameter does not match a valid url for the application

Tags: asana

So I am creating a simple web application using the MEAN stack. I am trying to connect to asana through asana connect using the browser pop-up example. For a simple test I have code that is nearly identical to the example, but I still get the error shown as the title for this question.

I'm not sure what might be going wrong but here is the code.

The authentication is supposed to happen after a button click. The client id, client secret are taken from my account settings on the main website. The redirect uri is also set to http://localhost:3000, so I know for sure that they match.

$scope.signIn = function(){

```
    var client = Asana.Client.create({
        clientId: My client id,
        clientSecret: my client secret,
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000'
    });

    client.useOauth(
        {
             flowType: Asana.auth.PopupFlow
        });

    client.authorize().then(function(){
        console.log("log-in success");
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
```

};

Comment: redirect to a html page, like, `redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/index.html'`

Comment: Oh wow that got through! Thank you so much, but could you explain why adding the html was difference?

Comment: There was no localhost:3000 is just the domain and it doesn't have any html to render.

Answer (score 0):

For the best user experience and for your application to work properly you want your redirect to accept the incoming HTTP request, parse out the `access_token` or `code` (depending on which grant flow) and subsequently render a page for the user.

You can read more about [authentication mechanisms on the Asana platform](https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/auth) in our documentation